# What might be a good way to get hands on experience with Object Oriented PHP

Tags: object-oriented, php, codeigniter, laravel

I am a Computer Science student. I took a course on OOP, and I understand the concepts (classes, extending, encapsulation, etc). I'm also a web developer, have been doing it for about three years; I've worked with Laravel and Codeigniter, but never really created classes my self. I want to hear what might be a good way to be excellent in OOP, applying all the knowledge and gaining experience at the same time.

Comment: ... by doing it? Think up any old application you might want to see created as a website, and create it. Release it as open source so you can get feedback.

Comment: I understand your question is directed to PHP, but actually OOP concepts are language agnostic, and the answers to [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-best-to-learn-oop-concepts-principles-practically) might be of help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the words of Nike and (recently) Shia LaBeouf, just do it. There are plenty of free resources online, though I utilized portions of [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430260319) to get me started. Just start messing around with the class-related syntax at first to get a feel for it and build some simple classes (I started with a class or two that did fantasy football point calculations). When you feel more confident, try building a small, simple application. As you immerse yourself into the task of actually building something, the right questions will arise and you will find the answers online, in the php documentation, by looking at other code, in that book or another book, or directly from others. You may even figure it out yourself and will become better at figuring it out yourself as you gain more experience. If you already have some object oriented experience, you really just need to learn PHP's syntax, and it is not that dissimilar from other class-based OO languages like Java. To summarize, building applications whether it be in your own time or professionally will really develop your skills. Working with and looking at frameworks like Laravel may help as well though I did not find this as helpful when I was initially starting out. Hope this helps! Good luck!